# Can't telnet to memcache server

Tags: telnet, memcache

I'm trying to connect the application server to the memcache server.

```
App Server 12.12.12.12
Memcache Server 13.13.13.13
Memcache Port 11211
```

I've tried the following.

```
Ping from 12.12.12.12 to 13.13.13.13 works
telnet 13.13.13.13 80 works
telnet 13.13.13.13 11211 doesn't work: No route to host found.
```

Memcache is listening to 127.0.0.1 and therefore the UFW on 13.13.13.13 is set to:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
11211/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
Anywhere                   ALLOW       13.13.13.13
127.0.0.1 11211/tcp        ALLOW       13.13.13.13
```

Still the server is not responding and result is No route or host found.

UFW logging is enabled but the ufw log can't be found at /var/log/ufw.log

No I'm at the point of being clueless...

[UPDATE]
Output of netstat -tunlp | grep 11211

```
tcp        0      0 13.13.13.13:11211       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14378/memcached
udp        0      0 13.13.13.13:11211       0.0.0.0:*                           14378/memcached
```

ps aux | grep memcache

```
memcache 14378  0.0  0.0 335580  1440 ?        Sl   15:56   0:00 /usr/bin/memcached -m 3584 -p 11211 -u memcache -l 13.13.13.13
```

Comment: Have you verified that `memcache` is running? Can you telnet to it from the server itself?

Comment: Disable firewall to check if port issue?

Comment: @FrankThornton than it gives me no route to host

Answer (score 2):

> Memcache is listening to 127.0.0.1

Well that's your problem. It's listening on a localhost address and as such, will not be available to other hosts on the network. You should have it listen on `0.0.0.0` (all addresses) or the specific non-localhost address required for your application.

Comment: Based on your comment, tried this: chanced memcached.conf to listen to -l 0.0.0.0 and added 
[0.0.0.0 11211              ALLOW       46.17.7.26] to the UFW. Doesn't work. Still no route to host. BTW ufw restarted, and memcached restarted

Comment: Tried to have it listen to its own ip adres (13.13.13.13) but that doesn't work either.

Comment: memcached.log is empty btw.

Comment: Are you even sure that memcached is running at all? Please update your question with the output of `$ netstat -tunlp | grep 11211` and `$ ps aux | grep memcache`.